# how to perform inner join on two table where i'am able to retrieve all data?

Tags: mysql, query, mariadb-10.5

I need help with a MySQL query.

- `bar_opening_details` has closing & opening stock
- `bar_recvd_details` has received the stock

When I receive purchased stock, I insert it into `bar_recvd_details`. Next, I will update `close_val` in `bar_opening_details` which is closing stock values of items.

When I join these two tables together, the number of rows returned from `bar_opening_details` is equal to the number of rows returned from `bar_recvd_details`. I.E. the unmatched rows of `bar_opening_details` are no longer returned.

The Fiddle is available [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9SMHPJsPPvkw2WMaQiJAx2/0)

Below is my desired output.

- I want to join the tables on `item_id`
- I want all data from each table, where the `<date column> = '2019-06-18'` from the respective table
- I also want data from `bar_recvd_details`, even if `recvd_value IS NULL`

**bar_opening_details**

```
SELECT *  FROM bar_opening_details
```

| item_cid | item_id | op_value | close_val | op_date | close_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 78 | 2 | 88 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 |
| 2 | 79 | 28 | 103 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 |
| 2 | 97 | 0 | 96 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 |
| 6 | 456 | 30 | 48 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 |
| 6 | 457 | 130 | 155 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 |
| 6 | 484 | 1 | 46 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 |
| 6 | 495 | 15 | 61 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 |
| 6 | 523 | 1 | 12 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 |
| 6 | 529 | 9 | 32 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 |
| 6 | 530 | 54 | 98 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 |
| 6 | 533 | 0 | 24 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 |
| 6 | 630 | 35 | 77 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 |
| 6 | 631 | 31 | 122 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 |
| 6 | 635 | 5 | 47 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 |
| 6 | 636 | 34 | 71 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 |

**bar_recvd_details**

```
SELECT *  FROM bar_recvd_details
```

| item_cid | item_id | recvd_date | recvd_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 637 | 2019-06-19 | 96 |
| 6 | 635 | 2019-06-19 | 48 |
| 6 | 637 | 2019-06-18 | 96 |
| 6 | 635 | 2019-06-18 | 48 |
| 6 | 636 | 2019-06-18 | 48 |
| 6 | 457 | 2019-06-18 | 48 |
| 6 | 456 | 2019-06-18 | 24 |
| 6 | 1432 | 2019-06-18 | 96 |
| 6 | 484 | 2019-06-18 | 48 |
| 6 | 523 | 2019-06-18 | 12 |
| 6 | 533 | 2019-06-18 | 24 |
| 4 | 79 | 2019-06-19 | 24 |
| 2 | 78 | 2019-06-19 | 24 |
| 6 | 529 | 2019-06-18 | 24 |

**Two tables Joined**

```
       SELECT 
            bar_opening_details.item_cid,
            bar_opening_details.item_id,
            bar_opening_details.op_value,
            bar_opening_details.close_val,
            bar_opening_details.close_date,
            bar_recvd_details.recvd_value,
            bar_recvd_details.recvd_date,
            bar_recvd_details.item_id
        FROM
            bar_opening_details
                LEFT JOIN bar_recvd_details 
                ON bar_recvd_details.item_id = bar_opening_details.item_id 
        where bar_opening_details.close_date = '2019-06-18'
```

| item_cid | item_id | op_value | close_val | close_date | recvd_value | recvd_date | item_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 79 | 28 | 103 | 2019-06-18 | 24 | 2019-06-19 | 79 |
| 2 | 78 | 2 | 88 | 2019-06-18 | 24 | 2019-06-19 | 78 |
| 2 | 97 | 0 | 96 | 2019-06-18 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 6 | 457 | 130 | 155 | 2019-06-18 | 48 | 2019-06-18 | 457 |
| 6 | 456 | 30 | 48 | 2019-06-18 | 24 | 2019-06-18 | 456 |
| 6 | 484 | 1 | 46 | 2019-06-18 | 48 | 2019-06-18 | 484 |
| 6 | 523 | 1 | 12 | 2019-06-18 | 12 | 2019-06-18 | 523 |
| 6 | 529 | 9 | 32 | 2019-06-18 | 24 | 2019-06-18 | 529 |
| 6 | 495 | 15 | 61 | 2019-06-18 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 6 | 533 | 0 | 24 | 2019-06-18 | 24 | 2019-06-18 | 533 |
| 6 | 530 | 54 | 98 | 2019-06-18 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 6 | 630 | 35 | 77 | 2019-06-18 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 6 | 635 | 5 | 47 | 2019-06-18 | 48 | 2019-06-19 | 635 |
| 6 | 635 | 5 | 47 | 2019-06-18 | 48 | 2019-06-18 | 635 |
| 6 | 636 | 34 | 71 | 2019-06-18 | 48 | 2019-06-18 | 636 |
| 6 | 631 | 31 | 122 | 2019-06-18 | (null) | (null) | (null) |

**Below is the output I would like**

| item_cid | item_id | op_value | close_val | close_date | recvd_value | recvd_date | item_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 97 | 0 | 96 | 2019-06-18 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 6 | 457 | 130 | 155 | 2019-06-18 | 48 | 2019-06-18 | 457 |
| 6 | 456 | 30 | 48 | 2019-06-18 | 24 | 2019-06-18 | 456 |
| 6 | 484 | 1 | 46 | 2019-06-18 | 48 | 2019-06-18 | 484 |
| 6 | 523 | 1 | 12 | 2019-06-18 | 12 | 2019-06-18 | 523 |
| 6 | 529 | 9 | 32 | 2019-06-18 | 24 | 2019-06-18 | 529 |
| 6 | 495 | 15 | 61 | 2019-06-18 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 6 | 533 | 0 | 24 | 2019-06-18 | 24 | 2019-06-18 | 533 |
| 6 | 530 | 54 | 98 | 2019-06-18 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 6 | 630 | 35 | 77 | 2019-06-18 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 6 | 635 | 5 | 47 | 2019-06-18 | 48 | 2019-06-18 | 635 |
| 6 | 636 | 34 | 71 | 2019-06-18 | 48 | 2019-06-18 | 636 |
| 6 | 631 | 31 | 122 | 2019-06-18 | (null) | (null) | (null) |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to join the tables on item_id

You're successfully doing this. You're justing using the wrong type of join.

> I also want data from bar_recvd_details, even if recvd_value IS NULL

You can't do this with an INNER JOIN. Instead, you need to use a LEFT JOIN to be able to return NULL from a table on the RIGHT side of the JOIN, where no data is present. For example, `LEFT JOIN bar_recvd_details b` instead of `INNER JOIN bar_recvd_details b`

> I want all data from each table, where the  = '2019-06-18' from the respective table

You' successfully doing this already. However, when moving to a LEFT JOIN, to meet the above criteria, you need to move that WHERE condition to the JOIN condition. I.E. `ON a.item_id=b.item_id AND b.recvd_date =  '2019-06-18'`

```
SELECT a.item_cid,
    a.item_id,
    a.op_value,
    a.close_val,
    a.op_date,
    a.close_date,
    b.recvd_value
FROM bar_opening_details AS a
    LEFT JOIN bar_recvd_details AS b
    ON a.item_id = b.item_id AND b.recvd_date = '2019-06-18'
WHERE a.close_date = '2019-06-18';
```

| tem_cid | item_id | op_value | close_val | op_date | close_date | recvd_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 78 | 2 | 88 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 | null |
| 2 | 79 | 28 | 103 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 | null |
| 2 | 97 | 0 | 96 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 | null |
| 6 | 456 | 30 | 48 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 | 24 |
| 6 | 457 | 130 | 155 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 | 48 |
| 6 | 484 | 1 | 46 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 | 48 |
| 6 | 495 | 15 | 61 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 | null |
| 6 | 523 | 1 | 12 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 | 12 |
| 6 | 529 | 9 | 32 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 | 24 |
| 6 | 530 | 54 | 98 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 | null |
| 6 | 533 | 0 | 24 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 | 24 |
| 6 | 630 | 35 | 77 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 | null |
| 6 | 631 | 31 | 122 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 | null |
| 6 | 635 | 5 | 47 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 | 48 |
| 6 | 636 | 34 | 71 | 2019-06-18 | 2019-06-18 | 48 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=abede993a01a9b0493c370a2aa33be85)

Comment: @BrendanMcCaffrey  item id is product id I may purchase stock on any date but when I receive them they should be added to **bar_opening_details** on the date i receive stock if i receive stock 2019-06-18 i want it be added to **bar_opening_details** on 2019-06-18 only

Comment: @gopal Do you expect item_ids 495, 530, 630 and 631 to be in the results? If not, what criteria excludes them?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ yes it should be